# ng2-dragula implement drag 'n drop one side with sorting and different template

Tags: javascript, html, angular, drag-and-drop, dragula

I've managed to get the drag and drop to work to only drop from one side to the other, but sorting is being cancelled out. I wish to be able to keep sorting on one side (target side) and not on the other side (source side).

Also, I wish to replace the HTMLElement with a different template when being dropped, and even better: while being dropped as well.

I find the documentation to be lacking clear use cases and would love to see how this could be done, and what I should be using.

This is my code so far:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {DragulaService} from "ng2-dragula";
import {DragAndDropHelper} from "../../../helpers/DragAndDropHelper";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-segment-dropzone',
    templateUrl: './segment-dropzone.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./segment-dropzone.component.scss']
})
export class SegmentDropzoneComponent {
    constructor(private dragulaService: DragulaService) {
        dragulaService.setOptions('elements-bag', {
            copy: true,
            copySortSource: true,
            accepts: function (el, target, source, sibling) {
                return target.id === 'elements-dropzone';
            },
        });
        dragulaService.drag.subscribe((value) => {
            this.getElementView(DragAndDropHelper.getElementIdFromDraggedItem(value[1]));
        });
    }

    public getElementView(elementId: string) {
        console.log(elementId);
    }
}
```

`target html`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <ul [dragula]='"elements-bag"' id="elements-dropzone">
            <li>first item</li>
            <li>second item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

`source html`

```
<div class="mt-list-container list-simple">
    <ul [dragula]='"elements-bag"' id="elements-list">
        <li class="mt-list-item" *ngFor="let element of elements" [attr.data-element-id]="element.id" >
            <div class="list-icon-container done">
                <i class="icon-check"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="list-datetime">{{ element.type }}</div>
            <div class="list-item-content">
                <h3 class="">{{ element.name }}</h3>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Goal in short:

1. Drag and drop only from the right to the left side: done, is
   done using `accept` property.
2. Allow sorting on the left side (target side, `id="elements-dropzone"`) only. Not on the right side!
3. Change element template while being dragged and after being dropped.

Would love to see any pointers on this. Thank you very much.

Comment: I also like to change the element while dragging. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Well, eventually I went with writing a dropzonecomponent which holds a list of dynamiccomponents. Upon dropping, the dynamiccomponent receives information from the dropped element, and renders the component (element) as expected. I than delete the dropped element. Not being the cleanest solution, it does work as expected and even allows me more customization.

Answer (score 0):

You can use native HTML drag and drop:

```
<script>
 function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
 ev.preventDefault();
 var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
 ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<img src="img_w3slogo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="88" height="31">
```

Comment: Appreciate the alternative. However, I do wish to use Dragula if possible as this also takes care of other things. You have experience with that?